# How to add ICEPusher object to a vertical layout in Vaadin 13

Tags: vaadin

I need to add pusher object to vertical layout in Vaadin 13

sources: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/icepush/samples

```
public class Playboard extends VerticalLayout
{
    private ICEPush pusher;


    public Playboard() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException{
        generateGUI();
    }

    private void generateGUI() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

..................
.................
pusher = new ICEPush();
VerticalLayout playboard = new VerticalLayout();

playboard.add(pusher);   //Cannot resolve method

...........
............
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - this is for the so called Vaadin Platform (Vaadin 6-8).  You have to find a web component replacement for that feature, write your own, or maybe sometime in the future there will be tooling to retrofit the old components into Vaadin Flow.

Comment: In addition, all you need to enable push in Vaadin 13 is to add the `@Push` annotation to your main layout. 

If you don't want changes to be pushed automatically, use `@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)` and `ui.push()`.

Comment: @Tazavoo   Yes, push does work but does not show any changes on UI until I do something in the same view (like clicking inside an edit box in the same view) that's why I tried ICEPush

Comment: @MadukaDeshanRodrigo Then push is not working (it's the whole point of push to send things down to the client asynchronously). If you have problems, please consider adding a new question and provide a minimal failing example)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do so? It states at add-on page that

> A component that adds push support to Vaadin!

Vaadin(both 7-8 versions as well as Flow 10+, which you are using) has a built-in support for Push currently, so there is no need to use a mentioned add-on. In the simplest case, all you need to do to get push working for your view is to add an annotation. There is a good official documentation on push:

- [Server Push Configuration](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html)
- [Asynchronous Updates](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html)

But,anyway, as mentioned in the previous answer you can't use the add-on with V13,since it's available only for Vaadin 6 and 7